# If I have multiple solutions or alternatives to a problem, should I post them as separate answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

After you have answered a question, the page shows the <kbd>Add Another Answer</kbd> button. Sometimes I combine all advice in one answer and may even include one or more alternatives to a problem.

Am I supposed to post these individually, so that the "best one" can be accepted? I assumed it was frowned upon posting multiple answers to a question unless it was some sort of community wiki form, like [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file), which currently has 108 answers, some of which are by the same author.

Instead of different authors giving different advice on a problem, the *same* author gives advice in different answers (which don't [contradict each other](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5676/should-i-post-two-answers-if-i-find-contradicting-arguments)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I post two answers if I find contradicting arguments?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5676/4398) and related to answers on [Why are answers so verbose?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/2812/4398)

Comment: Instead of different authors giving different advice on a problem, the *same* author gives advice in different answers, which don't contradict each other. Still, your first link was interesting to read, with KRyan's example answers.

Comment: I think the answers to the first link are still the right ones- they don't depend on the answers contradicting each other, just being different.

Answer (score 3):

I think, personally, that if the approaches are different "enough" that it makes good sense to post separate answers. I'll put forward two examples of mine: one I think is a clear-cut example of doing this appropriately, the other may be borderline.

In [How are "non-damage" attack rolls determined?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71888/23970) I present two different ways to handle OP's question. Both, I believe, are supported by the rules. But I think they're different enough that voters should be able to separately express their opinions. The disparity in votes on the answers may reflect the propriety of separating the answers, though it may just be a reflection of the post-dates for the two answers. (The high-voted answer was posted ten minutes after the question, the low-voted answer four days later.) In any case, *these answers are different in RPG-space, and certainly deserve to be voted on separately.*

In [Is "Unearthed Arcana: Players Make All Rolls" Correct?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69064/23970) I wrote two answers which--as a math teacher--I feel present markedly different ways of understanding the result. One is purely theoretical and tackles the general case, the other demonstrates the error in the UA article by looking at one specific example. I had in mind that one might seem obtuse and overwrought to some who might find the second perfectly suitable, while the second might seem underdeveloped and trivial to some who find the first a natural way of explaining. That said, they both arrive at the same conclusion (in mathematically identical ways) and don't fundamentally offer anything distinct *vis-a-vis* RPGs. The distinction between them is in mathematical presentation, but this isn't Math.SE. *Perhaps these should have been one answer.*